# Linq Update taking long time to process

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, linq

As my code is taking long time to process. I analyzed the code & searched the part of the code which is taking lots of time.

In my `listTempInOut` there are over 100000 records. `SDetails` also have more records. I wanted to `update` 2 fields in the model. So following is the code :-

```
var dataUpd = (from A in tempSS
                               from B in SDetails
                               from C in listTempInOut
                               where A.Id == B.Id
                               && A.Shift == B.Shift && A.Employee == C.Employee && A.SDate == C.Time_Date1
                               select new { A.SId, B.Status, C }).ToList();
                foreach (var row in dataUpd)
                {
                    row.C.Time_Field1 = row.ShiftId;
                    row.C.Time_Field2 = row.Status.ToString();
                }
```

What `change can i do` in the above code to `improve the performance` so that it takes less time to execute the code.

Comment: "1 lac records" ??

Comment: @Slugart: 1 lac is a measurement/counting unit -> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), though certainly not SI not even imperial :)

Comment: You may get better performance from using joins if your table structure allows for that

Comment: Which of the two lines is taking the time ? The ToList() or the loop ? In general ANY iterative updates on a database are going to take a lot of time and its one of the places you would loop to optimize out to a stored procedure

Comment: @PhillipH `ToList()` is taking the time.

Comment: Are you using the entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

Updates in the entity framework can be very slow, try setting the AutoDetectChangesEnabled property to false in your context (see code below, I'm not sure what your context is actually called so I called it "myContext"). You must remember to set it back to true when you are done with your updates so I'd recommend wrapping your code in a try/finally block.

```
        try
        {
            myContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            var dataUpd = (from A in tempSS
                           from B in SDetails
                           from C in listTempInOut
                           where A.Id == B.Id
                           && A.Shift == B.Shift && A.Employee == C.Employee && A.SDate == C.Time_Date1
                           select new { A.SId, B.Status, C }).ToList();
            foreach (var row in dataUpd)
            {
                row.C.Time_Field1 = row.ShiftId;
                row.C.Time_Field2 = row.Status.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            myContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: OP said that ToList is the culprit.

Comment: .ToList enumerates the query and gets the data from the database, but this will happen anyway as soon as you try to iterate through your collection in the foreach loop. It wouldn't harm to remove the "toList" call but I doubt any serious performance improvement would be observed. You could always try both and see how well they work?

Comment: I don't know if `tempSS` and `SDetails` represent database calls. OP doesn't give enough information.